# Proofs of Karpelevich's results about eigenvalues of nonnegative matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, nonnegative-matrices

Are there any books or papers written in English that contain proofs of the results obtained in the following paper?

> F.I. Karpelevich, [On the characteristic roots of matrices with nonnegative elements](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/f5bc094345e808f66058f5514348ec96/im3317.pdf), *Izv. Akad. Nauk SSSR Ker. Mat.*, 1951, v.15, issue 4, 361-383.

The statement without proof of Karpelevich's main result can be found in theorem 5.1 of the paper ***On $p$th roots of stochastic matrices*** by Higham and Lin. According to the authors, more details of Karpelevich's results can be found in Minc's book ***Nonnegative Matrices***, but again, without proofs.

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** I don't find any translation, but I have found a paper that restates Karpelevich's main theorem in a simpler form:

Ito, H., [A new statement about the theorem determining the region of eigenvalues of stochastic matrices](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0024-3795(97)80052-3). *Linear Algebra and its Applications*, 246: 241–246 (1997).

> Abstract
>
> Let $M_n$ denote the set of points in the complex plane that are eigenvalues of $n$-dimensional stochastic matrices. The set $M_n$ is completely determined by the Karpelevich theorem, the statement of which, however, is lengthy and intricate. The paper shortens the presentation of the theorem.

Note that this paper does not prove Karpelevich's theorem. It only proves that the author's restatement of the theorem is equivalent to Karpelevich's original formulation.